# Getting values from JSON object against key

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, hapi.js

I trying to parse the json object but having the hard time. 
this i what I am trying to do

```
var dat = {array:test};
    console.log("testing" + JSON.stringify(dat.array[0]));
    for(var i = 0; i < dat.array.length; i++) {
        console.log("testing" + JSON.stringify(dat.array[i]));
    }
```

The data is in "test" variable which is getting data from DB. the test object is as follow

```
 [ [ { id: 123456,
      Key 1: ‘some value’,
      Key 2: ‘another  value’,
      Key 3: 'Frontpage'
} ],
  [ { id: 123456,
      Key 1: ‘some value’,
      Key 2: ‘another  value’,
      Key 3: 'Frontpage'
 } ] ]
```

I need to get value against each key.
Expected output

```
{ id: 123456,
      Key 1: ‘some value’,
      Key 2: ‘another  value’,
      Key 3: 'Frontpage'
 }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the expected output when running the code?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: What is the data type of `test`? Is it a JavaScript array or is it a string variable in JSON encoding?

Comment: javascript array

Comment: the data in "test" is written above

Comment: OK, so it is not JSON, and you are not parsing JSON. In that case I don't see  what the problem is. The code you posted works (it outputs something useful). You could just add `[0]` to take care of the nested array level: `JSON.stringify(dat.array[i][0])`.

Answer (score 0):

if Ive understood your question correctly I hope this piece of code will help you:

```js
const assert = require('assert')

const test = [
  [
    {
      'id': 123456,
      'Key 1': 'some value',
      'Key 2': 'another  value',
      'Key 3': 'Frontpage'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      'id': 123456,
      'Key 1': 'some value',
      'Key 2': 'another  value',
      'Key 3': 'Frontpage'
    }
  ]
]

const expected = [{
  'id': 123456,
  'Key 1': 'some value',
  'Key 2': 'another  value',
  'Key 3': 'Frontpage'
},
{
  'id': 123456,
  'Key 1': 'some value',
  'Key 2': 'another  value',
  'Key 3': 'Frontpage'
}]

const dat = { array: test }
const actual = dat.array.reduce((p, n, index) => p.concat(n[index - 1]))

// test
assert.deepEqual(actual, expected)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = [
  [{
    id: 123456,
    Key1: "some value",
    Key2: "another  value",
    Key3: "Frontpage"
  }],
  [{
    id: 123456,
    Key1: "some value",
    Key2: "another  value",
    Key3: "Frontpage"
  }]
]



var dat = { array: test };
test.forEach(function (elem) {
  elem.forEach(function (obj) {
    console.log(obj)
  })
})
```